# How to find the index in ArrayBuffer using scala

Tags: scala

For example:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
val times = ArrayBuffer(Some("Last week"), Some("Last month"), Some("Last year"))
```

How do I find the index of Last year/Last month/... in this array buffer?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `indexOf`

```scala
times.indexOf(Some("Last month")) // returns 1
```

#### Update

You can convert the times `ArrayBuffer[Option[String]]` into a `ArrayBuffer[String]` via

```
val l = times.map(_.getOrElse("")) // ArrayBuffer("Last week", "Last month", ...)
```

And then you can search for the strings

```
l.indexOf("Last month")
```

Comment: How to convert in list (Remove Some )for eg: List("Last week", "Last month". "Last year")

Comment: Understood that you answered his question, Till. But, calling `times.map(_.getOrElse("")` adds an additional walk of the list - certainly not necessary for what you're trying to do.

Comment: You're right @KevinMeredith. This is not the most efficient solution. If you want to convert the list from `List[Option[String]]` to `List[String]` and find the index of the element with a certain value in one pass, then you can combine it in the `map` function. However, you basically double the operations of your map function, which will lead to the same complexity as with the two pass approach (assuming that you have only few cache misses).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `indexOf` or `lastIndexOf`. Example:

```
 times indexOf ( Some( "Last year" ) )
```

Also you can use `indexWhere` or `lastIndexWhere`. For example:

```
times indexWhere { _.get == "Last year" }
```

Answer (score 1):

*Perhaps* not as efficient as `indexOf`, but more readable, I'd argue:

```
scala> times.zipWithIndex.find( 
      { case (value, _) => value == Some("Last week") } 
).map(_._2)
res7: Option[Int] = Some(0)
```

Or, using `flatMap`:

```
scala> times.zipWithIndex.flatMap { 
     |    case (value, index) => value match { 
     |                   case Some("Last week") => ArrayBuffer(index)
     |                   case _                 => Nil 
     |                 }
     | }
res2: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer(0)
```

Comment: I could not use the indexOf approach. I used this approach as my object in the ArrayBuffer was not simple String - but a  complex one. I used one of the attributes to find the object and zipWithIndex helped getting the index.